# DMBS_OUTPUT --> DMBS_SCHEDULER

Tags: oracle, procedure, dbms-scheduler, dbms-output

I use a DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TEST') in a procedure to check every call of these procedure. The procedure is called by DBMS_SCHEDULER. job --> schedule every minute.

But there is no output on my DBMS_OUTPUT in my Developer.
Log-Table listed perferct values : every minutes one job --> finished successful.

but why there is no output shown .
Output is turned on.
DB Oracle 11g

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dbms_scheduler does not show dbms_output. The better ways is as you did: write to a table.

Comment: The OP didn't specify his oracle version, but as of 12c, jobs executed bia DBMS_Scheduler will log output from DBMS_OUTPUT calls. See https://connor-mcdonald.com/2016/06/27/dbms_output-and-the-scheduler/

Answer (score 2):

Although this may not be the best way to instrument your code, but starting from version 12c, `dbms_output` messages within `dbms_scheduler` jobs are stored and visible in `USER|ALL|DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS` views.

See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-E87CA539-38E8-41A4-B10B-784308A56F02.htm#REFRN20386 , columns `ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS.OUTPUT` and `ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS.BINARY_OUTPUT`

Answer (score 1):

Either write your output to table like you already did or use UTL_FILE to ship it out to the DB server.